# How can I execute VB code entered in a textbox

Tags: vb.net

How can I have a button execute VB code I entered in a text box?

E.g. when I wrote this in text box:

```
form1.Show()
```

and the button is clicked, `form1` will be shown.

Comment: Don't do this this. There are MASSIVE security implications around this kind of feature.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: In my program, when I click on a specific button, a form will appear in it. WebBrowser will go to the links shortcut site (in order to get money), and upon completion it will run another form, I have a lot of these buttons and I do not want to make more of this form

Comment: I want a model to be modified when pressing such buttons, such as when pressing one of the buttons, the end direction will be changed to another model.

Comment: If WebBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains(TextBox2.Text) Then
            Button1.Hide()
            GroupBox1.Hide()
        ElseIf WebBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains(TextBox3.Text) Then
            Form3.Show()
            Me.Close()
   End If
i just want Modify this "Form3.Show()"
When i press a button in another form

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is like `eval()` for javascript or PHP.

.Net (including the VB, C#, and F# languages) is a *general purpose* platform, where javascript and PHP are intended for more specialized situations (javascript is usually in a browser with limited APIs, and PHP was originally a web CGI platform only).

It's okay for a specialized language, which can be sandboxed and  API-limited, to include an eval() feature. But for a generalized language, which needs access to all of APIs in a system, this is *extremely dangerous*. There are **MASSIVE** security implications. As a result, this kind of thing is not impossible (there's CodeDOM, Roslyn, compile+Reflection.Load, etc), but none of them are quick or simple to do. There's not a simple `eval()` function out of the box. And that's a good thing.

Comment: If WebBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains(TextBox2.Text) Then Button1.Hide() GroupBox1.Hide() ElseIf WebBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains(TextBox3.Text) Then Form3.Show() Me.Close() End If i just want Modify this "Form3.Show()" When i press a button in another form